# How Can i Access the button inflated using fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

My complete code is given here. But not showing the Activity.
Showing null pointer Exception when adding clickListener().

How Can i Access the button inflated using fragment

//Cant add complete code. Showing add more details.//

```
 public class Activity extends Activity{

        private static final String KEY_SUCCESS="success";


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Fragment fragment=new PlaceholderFragment();
            transaction.add(R.id.container,fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack("welcome");
            transaction.commit();

            }



        /**
         * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
         */
        public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
           Button loginButton;

            private String userNameString;
            private String passwordString;

            public PlaceholderFragment() {
            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView;
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);

                try{
                    loginButton= (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.LoginFormButton);
                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent logIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), BearerLoggedActivity.class);
                        startActivity(logIntent);
                    }
                });
                return rootView;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am still not cleared.

Comment: What is line 45 in WelcomeActivity.java?

Comment: loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){}

Comment: Now I am cleared. I use fragments OnActivityCreated() and implemented the click event. Thank you all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
  fragment.getView().findViewById(id)
```

That should do it, but I usually prefer to have all my listeners and business logic in the Fragment itself keeping the Activity as minimal possible. A small demo :

```
  public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

Button btn;
private OnFragmentClickListener listener;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
    ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment,
            container, false);
    //Do stuff to the fragment view in here if you want

    btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.breplace);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                MyActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Can I use Intents in this way??

Comment: public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView;
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, true);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

I am using this class inside activity.

Comment: Just before you call return rootView implement your button onClick listener and start the activity.

Comment: Post your logcat and we should be able to debug

Comment: added the log cat. Please check it

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, what you are looking for is:

```
fragment.getView().findViewById(id);
```

Comment: Which is the exception? If it is NullPointerException, then you are calling the method too soon. The layout hasn't been created, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this on your Fragment class

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, container, false);
    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    //imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
    //imageView.setBackgroundResource(imageResourceId);

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent mainIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                NextActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Your problem will be solved

Comment: My problem still continues. Showing NullPointerException.

Comment: @Rashid when at the time of loading or when you have click the button ?

Comment: Its not showing the activity. Before that showing Fatal error.

Comment: That means before fragment load it will show error or when click on button then it will does not show any activity?

Comment: yes sure. Its not showing anything. Showing error in the onclicklistener Function.